# access a hive table specifying database qualifier in spark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to access a hive table specifying database qualifier using spark sql. I am using sparksession as it is spark 2.0 or above. For example, I am trying to add a partition to an existing table. The query is

sparksession.sql("ALTER TABLE $databasename.$tablename ADD PARTITION (...) LOCATION ...")

It doesn't throw any error but not even creating any partition. Is it the case that I can't specify databaseName in spark sql?

Comment: Can you please share the code and spark Logs?

Comment: It's a very big code. Inside that I am implementing a method. Can't share the whole code, basically the code is creating a query which looks like : ALTER TABLE databaseName.tableName ADD PARTITION (partitioncolumns = 'value') LOCATION 'some s3 location'

Comment: Can you see the spark logs when it is executing this sql?

Comment: It runs perfectly when I don't specify database name, i.e. while it uses the default database.

Comment: Yeah, sparks logs says retries for twice or thrice and then it just stops without throwing an error. I am runnig the spark code on EMR

Comment: For a long time, Hive itself did not support `Db.Table` notation for ALTER commands... Although it worked for any other command. Now it is fixed in Hive 2.x but Spark appears to be lagging...

Answer (score 1):

```
use Database
```

Command is supported in Latest Spark version you can use

```
sparksession.sql("use $databasename");
sparksession.sql("ALTER TABLE $tablename ADD PARTITION (...) LOCATION ...");
```

Try using the above code this can solve you problem.

Comment: Use database statement works. But, I want to specify databaseName in query itself if it is possible. As there are different methods and I don't want to use two different SQL if it can be done in a single query.